# Bash How to get second to last char of string?

Tags: bash

There is a nice answer to get last char of string

```
str='abcd/'
echo "${str: -1}"
```

how to get second to last i.e. return 'd' instead of '/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str='abcd/'
echo "${str: -2:-1}"
```

returns 'd'

Answer (score 5):

As you already seem to know, negative positions are relative to the *end* of the string, so `-1` starts at the last character, `-2` would start at the penultimate character, and so forth.

However, the form you use is the *simplified* form of taking the substring, it takes *all* characters from the specified position to the end of the string.

You can also supply an *explicit* length to get a limited number of characters starting at the position so, to get the second last character, all you need is:

```
${str: -2:1}
```

---

The relevant bits of the `bash` documentation are:

> `${parameter:offset}`
> `${parameter:offset:length}`
>
> Substring Expansion. Expands to up to `length` characters of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by `offset`.
>
> If `length` is omitted, expands to the substring of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by `offset` and extending to the end of the value.